# Python, if statement not working - Blynk Raspberry Pi

Tags: python

I have some code which uses a Blynk library and a pyblynk library. However with the if statement at the bottom, when I change any variable, it doesn't seem to be updating upon running the script. It still outputs it as default

Here is my script:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(
    os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__),
        '..'
    )
)
import pigpio
from gpiozero import Button, OutputDevice

auth_token = 'b3e6cf1a32c54bdd87018f91cfb71e85'
addr = '127.0.0.1'
import lib.hw as blynk_hw
import lib.client as blynk_client

class myHardware(blynk_hw.Hardware):
    """
        you'll probably have to overload the On* calls,
        see lib/hw.py
    """
    pass

cConnection=blynk_client.TCP_Client(addr)
if not cConnection.connect():
    print('Unable to connect')
    sys.exit(-1)

if not cConnection.auth(auth_token):
    print('Unable to auth')

cHardware=myHardware(cConnection)

try:
    while True:
        cHardware.manage()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    raise



def OnVirtualWrite(self,pin,val):
    if pin == 1:
        print('Lightbulb On')
    elif pin == 1 and val == '0':
        print('Lightbulb Off')             
    else:
        print('dawdawda',pin,val)
```

Output:

```
(20, 18, 6)
('OnVirtualWrite', 1, u'1')
(20, 19, 6)
('OnVirtualWrite', 1, u'0')
```

Comment: I don't see where that printed output is generated?

Comment: The second branch will never get called, because it’ll go through the first instead, but it doesn’t look like any of the `if` branches are printing where you’re looking and I don’t see anything that looks like it *can* generate the output you’re seeing anyway.

Comment: Also, what exactly is part of the class? Everything under `class myHardware(blynk_hw.Hardware):`? Your indentation seems to be off.

Comment: @roganjosh I think so, given that `OnVirtualWrite` has a `self` parameter. I wish SO used fenced code blocks, because it’s much easier to get indentation problems this way.

Comment: I've kinda followed a tutorial to run Blynk with python, and neither do I see where its coming from, because this is all thats in the file. I've put it into another file and ran that, still same output.

Comment: if you match the first of an `if`/`elif`/`else` then why would you move to the next? it needs to be something like `if pin == 1 and val != 0:

Comment: @DanielH except there's a `pass` right under the class definition. I'm confused.

Comment: What values are you running it with? `(1, u'1')` and `(1, u'0')`? Also, this looks like a web app; are you looking at the web page in the browser, or in the console?

Comment: This is the git repo I've been using https://github.com/erazor83/pyblynk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python methods need to be *inside* their classes. To override the `OnVirtualWrite` method, instead of putting it at the end of the file you need to delete the `pass` statement under `class myHardware` and put it there instead, indented under the `class`:

```
class myHardware(blynk_hw.Hardware):
    """
        you'll probably have to overload the On* calls,
        see lib/hw.py
    """
    def OnVirtualWrite(self,pin,val):
        if pin == 1 and val == u'1':
            print('Lightbulb On')
        elif pin == 1 and val == u'0':
            print('Lightbulb Off')             
        else:
            print('dawdawda',pin,val)
```

This tells Python that `OnVirtualWrite` is a part of `myHardware` and not an unrelated function.

I also added `and val == u'1'` to the first branch of the `if` statement, because otherwise the lightbulb would always be turned on even if `val` was `'0'`, and I changed the string literals to Unicode because that’s what’s being provided as input and you should try to keep byte strings and character strings as separate ideas.

Comment: I actually cannot thank you enough. This has saved me so much time. Thank you :) Working perfectly